# Where to get simple Android programs to illustrate the lifecycle?

Tags: android, lifecycle

I was following "hello-android-introducing-googles-mobil… by Ed Burnette.. which was very useful for the basics. Morover using the basics I was able to create a small calculator application.

But when I wanted to work with activities(life cycle) I couldnt follow the book clearly..

So please suggest a book or site which explains the life cycle of android applications with simple 
easy to read (and workout) programs

Comment: If you would like to see another simple app, I wrote an open source tipping calculator that you can take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/ and I also blogged about what I learned from it http://www.bryandenny.com/index.php/2010/05/25/what-i-learned-from-writing-my-first-android-application/

Comment: `But when I wanted to work with activities(life cycle)` You're ALWAYS working with activity lifecycles, whether you know it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two books, but I'd also like to suggest an actual empirical test that you should try.

### To answer your original question:

Commonsware is a good source and Mark Murphy has a badge cred on Stack Overflow.

The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development, from Commonsware.com

I've had good mileage on pages 8 & 9 of this book from O'Reilly.  I found that in order to fully grasp the Android Life cycle I had to read these pages at least 10 times.
Android Application Development, ISBN 978-0596521479

### Suggestion for empirical testing

of the [Android activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Create an android Activity or sample app, and log each time one of the Android Lifecycle methods has been entered.  As in this sample.

Add these logs entries to your activity, then build it.  Run it on a device or on the emulator with `adb logcat` running.  Then do some experiments.  See what happens when you lock the screen,
press home, press 'menu', etc.  This method will help you understand than just reading.  You will still need to read and study the activity lifecycle, but this will help quite a bit.

```
public class YourActivity 
{
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "YourActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate()");
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart()");
      super.onStart();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStop()");
      super.onStop();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");
      super.onDestroy();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause()");
      super.onPause();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume()");
      super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sams teach yourself android isbn-13: 978-0-321-67335-0